# Derivative of a random process using a Karhunen-Loève-expansion/basis expansion

Tags: derivatives, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

Suppose a random function $X(t)$ can be written with the help of the Karhunen-Loève expansion (or some other basis expansion) by 
$$X(t) = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \xi_k \psi_k(t),$$
where  $\psi_1(t), \psi_2(t),\dots$ are orthonormal eigenfunctions corresponding to the non-negative eigenvalues $\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\dots$ of the covariance operator $\Gamma$ and the random variables $\xi_k = \int_{a}^bX(s)\psi_k(s)ds$  are the uncorrelated scores with $E(\xi_k)=0$, $E(\xi_k \xi_l)=0$  for $k\neq l$ and $E(\xi_k^2)=\lambda_k$.

I am interested in the derivative $X'(t)$ of $X(t)$. Suppose the eigenfunctions $\psi_k(t)$ are differentiable, then, a natural approach would be to use the basis expansion above to get

$$X'(t) = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \xi_k \psi_k'(t).$$

This approach doesn't work always. For example, in the case where $X(t)$ is a Wiener process, $\psi_k(t)=\sqrt{2}\sin((k-1/2)\pi t)$ and $\lambda_k \sim 1/k^2$. However, while the derivative of $\psi_k$ exists and is obviously bounded, it is well known that the Wiener process is a.s. not differentiable.

Why can't I see this fact from the derivative of the expansion? Which property am I missing?

(What irritates me additionally is the fact that the variance of the right hand side, $E((\sum_{k=1}^\infty \xi_k \psi_k'(t))^2) = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \lambda_k \psi_k'(t)^2 \leq const \sum_{k=1}^\infty 1/k^2$, is bounded?!)

Can someone enlighten me why this natural approach doesn't work in general and/or give me some conditions when it works?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is very analogous to Fourier series expansion. Try expanding a straight square wave in a Fourier series, and you will see the [Gibbs phenomenon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gibbs_phenomenon). It essentially comes down to the fact that you'll have pointwise convergence, but not uniform convergence. The [Dirichlet conditions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_conditions) give you some limit on the sorts of behavior allowed in your $X(t)$ in order to get better behavior in the convergence. That, at least, works for Fourier series; however, any sort of eigenvector expansion such as you're employing, especially if it's an orthonormal expansion, will behave much like a Fourier series.